# Activity which downloads data in background with service and doesn't get destroyed on hitting back button

Tags: android

I need to develop an application with downloads the data at the background and update about the progress in the front.

I guess this can be achieved using services and activity and passing data in between the. But, what I need to do is even if I hit back button and then start the activity again. It should check if the service is running or not. If service is not running it should start one else it should display the data from running service.

Something like music player where music is played by a service at a background and activity displays the information. Even on browsing through other activities of the application or hitting back, state of the music player is maintained.

Cheers,
Prateek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Prateek,

Service can be started at any time you set & can be destroyed after you complete the task.
For further help have a look @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService .

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware that service can be started and destroyed at any time. I have a activity which starts a service. Now if this activity is destroyed on hitting back and user again starts the same activity, then the service shouldn't be started again instead I should be able to fetch the information from the running service and display it on the front end. If the service is not running, then the one should be started. Thanks

Comment: @Prateek Simply write a method containing your logic (that checks a boolean value isRunning in Service) in Activity's onStart().If you are worried about Activity & Service communication then use the Application Class you can extend this class to keep track of global application state.